# How to make mesh layer visible in JPEG map using Jupyter from QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, rendering, jupyter-notebook

I am working with an active QGIS project. I have few layers in the .qgz file. All I want is to have a .png format map from this .qgz file using jupyter. I have added the code below.

```
from qgis.gui import QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge, QgsMapCanvas
from qgis.core import*
app=QgsApplication([],True)
app.setPrefixPath("C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.30.0", True)
app.initQgis()
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read(r"C:\Users\V01.qgz")
#The layer I want to have in map
myMeshLayer  = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("BaseFlood Map_Day05")[0]
layoutmanager = project.layoutManager()
layout = layoutmanager.layoutByName("Day_4")
map_label = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
layout.removeLayoutItem(map_label)
layout.addLayoutItem(map_label)
map_label.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(1.6, 0.5, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutInches))
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToImage(r"C:\Day-1.png", QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings() )
```

Using this code I am getting all layers except the QgsMeshLayer layer in the image.Why I am not getting the mesh layer (blue layer present in the 2nd image) in Jupyter map when this layer is present in the QGIS? I have used external driver that is not shipped directly with MDAL installations for DFSU file (mesh layer).

This is how it looks in the QGIS main window
[image]

This is what I get by the code as an image
[image]

These are the layers present in QGIS file.
[image]